# I am in php bin/magento setup:upgrade Something goes wrong

Tags: magento-2.1

[image]
I am in php bin/magento setup:upgrade Something goes wrong，My Magento is a community edition with version number 2.1.13
Please help me thank you

Comment: Do you have the class inside `vendor/magento/framework/Serialize` folder?

Comment: My vendor/magento/framework/Serialize not this class

Comment: Without this class, what do I do

Comment: please run this command composer require laminas/laminas-serializer  

OR

added below line in your composer.json file.

"laminas/laminas-serializer": "^2.12",

Answer (score 0):

You have serializer class missing please install it using these steps :
composer require zendframework/zend-serializer --no-update
composer update zendframework/zend-serializer

Answer (score 0):

composer dump-autoload

still facing issue then run

composer require symfony/serializer